# Problemas para contar e agrupar campos no banco de dados

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Estou começando a estudar a linguagem SQL e a interação entre as tabelas, e me deparei com um exercício de uma lista que não estou conseguindo resolver.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ele pede o seguinte:

> Para cada produto existente diga quais vendas foram realizadas e
>   quantos itens foram pedidos.

Tentei essa solução, mas não alcancei a resposta esperada:

```
SELECT
    p.nome, COUNT(i.fk_venda)AS qtd_venda
FROM
    tb_produto AS p, tb_itens AS i
WHERE
    p.pk_produto=i.fk_produto
GROUP BY
    p.nome;
```

Comment: O seu script imprime qual resultado ?

Comment: @TulioCalil ele agrupa todos os itens registrados, com a exceção de um deles. E a soma das quantidades vendidas não bate com o que registrei anteriormente.

Comment: Tem como exportar o banco pra eu entender melhor aqui ?

Comment: @TulioCalil o Caique solucionou a minha dúvida, mas agradeço ainda sim por sua atenção!

Comment: De nada! Boa sorte e sucesso!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que entendi da sua pergunta seria o seguinte.

Exibir a quantidade de itens agrupando pela venda e pelo produto, exibir a descrição do produto, exibir a identificação da venda.

Veja se o select abaixo te atende, caso não nos mostre o que ele retorna.

```
SELECT
     p.nome           [Produto]
   , fk_venda         [idVenda]
   , COUNT(i.pk_item) [QuantidadeItens]
FROM
    tb_produto 
INNER JOIN tb_itens AS i
   ON p.pk_produto = i.fk_produto
GROUP BY
    p.nome, fk_venda;
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo que eu estava tentando! Antes pelo jeito que fiz ele agrupava todas as vendas de um produto, ou seja, ele não exibia as vendas separadamente como o pedido pelo exercício. Com essa sua solução, as identificações das vendas foram separadas, e os itens contabilizados de acordo com o produto. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Exato, magina. Fico feliz em ajudar